# Proof that $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} V_{n} \neq \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology

I don't know how to start with this problem, it would be very helpful if you help me with some suggestions, please.

The problem:

Let $\{ V_{n} \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ a sequence of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^p$ such that $V_n \neq \emptyset$. $\overline{V}_{n}$ is compact and $\overline{V_n} \subseteq V_{n-1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Proof that $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} V_{n} \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: What does it mean that $\cap_n V_n \not=\emptyset$ by definition?

Comment: Please share first your thoughts about the problem.

Comment: You know that $V_1$ is nonempty, since you're told $V_n \neq \emptyset$ for all $n$. Since $\overline{V}_n \subset V_{n-1}$ for all $n$, what can you say about the relationship of each $V_n$ to $V_1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any statement about open sets has a "dual" about closed sets. Sometimes the "dual" can be usefully re-formed.

Definition: A non-empty family $F$ of subsets of a space X is said to have the Finite Intersection Property (FIP) when $\cap G\ne\emptyset$ for every non-empty finite $G\subseteq F.$

Definition: A space $X$ is compact iff every open cover of $X$ has a finite sub-cover.

The "dual" is: A space $X$ is compact iff $\cap F\ne \emptyset$ whenever $F$ is a non-empty closed family in $X$ with the FIP. (A "closed family" means a family of closed sets. It does $not$ mean  a closed set. A family in $X$ means a set of subsets of $X$.) Proof:

(i).If $\cap F=\emptyset$ then $ \{X\setminus f: f\in F\}$ is an open cover of $X$ with no finite sub-cover. (ii). If $C$ is an open cover of $X$ with no finite sub-cover then $F=\{X\setminus c: c\in C\}$ is a non-empty closed family in $X$ with the FIP, and $\cap F=\emptyset.$

In your Q, let $X= \overline  {V_1}$ and $F=\{\overline {V_n}: n\in\Bbb N\}.$

Note that it us not necessary for any $V_n$ to be open, and the condition $\overline V_n\subset V_{n-1}$ can be weakened to $\overline V_n\subseteq \overline {V_{n-1}}$.

Comment: We can also use sequences: For each $n$ take $x_n\in V_n.$ Since ($x_n)_n$ is a sequence in the compact set $\bar V_1,$ we can find a strictly increasing $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ such that $(x_{f(n)})_n$ converges to some $x. $ Now for each $n$ the sequence  $(x_{f(j)})_{f(j)\ge n}$ is in the compact set $\bar V_n$, & converges to $x,$ so $x\in\bar V_n.$ Finally, for each $n$ we have $x\in\bar V_{n+1}\subset V_n$ so $x\in V_n.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use nonemptiness and the relation between them to build a sequence of points where each $x_n$ is in $V_n \setminus V_{n+1}$. Use sequential compactness to get the limit point $x$. How can you conclude from here?